# Duplicate 'begin_checkout' event firing in GA4 - There's no GTM tag either

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm seeing the 'begin_checkout' event firing twice from one button click in the GA4 debug view. It's a Wordpress site with Woocommerce using GA Google Analytics plugin. We don't have any tags on the site with GTM which is commonly cited as the cause of this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

GTM is commonly cited as the cause of this issue, but with no active tags there's not really any other options I can try. I'm an analyst without dev experience so anything technical will be pushed back to the client.